# Displaying image saved in data type - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to display a png image to the screen that is saved in binary in the database. Here is my current attempt and failure messages.

### Controller:

```
def index
  @failed_images = FailedImage.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page])
end
```

### View:

```
<% @failed_images.each do |image| %>
  <%= image.md5 %>
  <%= image.data.encode!('UTF-8') %>
<% end %>
```

### Error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
   "\xEF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

Basically I just want to display the image on the screen with a size that I can define. I have never done this before so any help would be grand!

Comment: Is it stored as a base64 stream encapsulating a png?

Comment: I'm not sure? How can I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 is a text encoding, so it doesn't make sense to use it for image data. Instead you should use the [data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) inside an `img` tag. Something like this:

```
<%= image_tag "data:image/png;base64,#{Base64.encode64(image.data).gsub("\n", "")}" %>
```